# Select from table based on conditions from on another meta table and user input

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, schema, mariadb

What I need is to retrieve available 'cars' from table-1 based on existing 'reservations' saved on the same table, where both 'car' and 'reservation' have the same meta table that holds the reservation's start date and end time in key=>value columns in the meta table, for example:

carA has the following reservations:

1. 4-July to 8-July
2. 9-July to 14-July
3. 18-July to 20-July

If a user queries available cars from 15-July to 17-July, carA should be returned as available.
If queries available cars from 14-July to 17-July, carA is not available.
If queries available cars from 16-July to 18-July, carA is not available.
If queries available cars from 16-July to 21-July, carA is not available.

To further elaborate, Here is the simplified database schema:

Table 1 - items
Table 2 - items-meta

### Tabel 1 (items)

```
+------+-----------------+--------------+
| id   |   type          |     item     |
+------+-----------------+--------------+
|  1   |   car           |     carA     |
|  2   |   car           |     carB     |    
|  3   |   car           |     carC     |  
|  18  |   car           |     carD     |    
|  4   |   reservation   | reservationA |
|  5   |   reservation   | reservationB |
|  6   |   reservation   | reservationC |
|  7   |   reservation   | reservationD |
|  8   |   reservation   | reservationE |
|  9   |   reservation   | reservationF |
|  10  |   reservation   | reservationH |
|  11  |   reservation   | reservationI |
+------+-----------------+--------------+
```

### Tabel 2 (items-meta)

```
+-----+---------+--------------+---------------------+
| id  |   rid   |    key       |        value        |
+-----+---------+--------------+---------------------+
|  1  |    4    |  start_time  | 2018-07-4 11:51:34  |
|  2  |    4    |  end_time    | 2018-07-8 11:51:34  |
|  3  |    4    |  car_id      | 1                   |
|  4  |    5    |  start_time  | 2018-07-9 11:51:34  |
|  5  |    5    |  end_time    | 2018-07-14 11:51:34 |
|  6  |    5    |  car_id      | 1                   |
|  7  |    6    |  start_time  | 2018-07-18 11:51:3  |
|  8  |    6    |  end_time    | 2018-07-20 11:51:34 |
|  9  |    6    |  car_id      | 1                   |
|  10 |    7    |  start_time  | 2018-07-18 11:51:3  |
|  11 |    7    |  end_time    | 2018-07-20 11:51:34 |
|  12 |    7    |  car_id      | 18                  |
+-----+---------+--------------+---------------------+
```

I think this is an interesting challenge, any idea how should be the query structured to server that purpose, is it even possible? appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Do you have any control over the structure of the tables?   This could be solved in an easier fashion if the data was structured in a more normalized format.   If you do have control over the data structure, I can make some recommendations.

Comment: unfortunately no @Chanicho, if we can restructure the schema, this wouldn't be a challenge..thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I created a subquery that transforms the items-meta data into a single table with a car ID, reservation ID, start time, and end time. This is represented in the query below as table R.    Once the data is in this format, you can query the reservation data to see where there are any overlaps between your search dates and existing reservations.

The following query gives a list of all reservations that conflict with the given search dates.     You could use this list to know which cars to exclude because they are already reserved during the search dates.

```
set @SearchStartTime  = cast('2018-07-03 00:00:00' as datetime);
set @SearchEndTime  = cast('2018-07-05 00:00:00' as datetime);


select carID, rid, StartTime, EndTime from
(
          select Cars.`value` as carID, coalesce(Starts.rid, Ends.rid) as rid, StartTime, EndTime from
          (select id, rid, `value`  from items_meta 
          where `key`='car_id' ) Cars
          left outer join 
          (select id, rid, cast(`value` as datetime) as StartTime from items_meta 
          where `key`='start_time' ) Starts
          on Starts.rid = Cars.rid
          left outer join 
          (
          select id, rid, cast(`value` as datetime)as EndTime from items_meta 
          where `key`='end_time') Ends
          on Ends.rid = Cars.rid

 ) R
where 
(
@SearchStartTime between R.StartTime and R.EndTime
or
@SearchEndTime between R.StartTime and R.EndTime
or
R.StartTime between @SearchStartTime and @SearchEndTime
or
R.EndTime between @SearchStartTime and @SearchEndTime
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but not the answer I was looking for, it needs to be a query to process that in mysql.

Comment: I updated the answer so that it is written for MySQL